# Embed or Include Content from another Page in the Same Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, content, embedded

I need to have a piece of content show up on a couple of hundred other pages without copy/pasting it all of the place. I'd like this to come in just as it appears on the source page (or whatever) but without headers and chrome and such.

The goal is to be able to edit the information in a single place and have those edits reflected in all of the pages wherein this chunk is embedded.

I'm using the online O365 SharePoint modern pages, and am NOT a site admin, so no solutions that involve installing plugins or admin rights or SharePoint 2010.

I feel certain that there must be an easy way to do this, however I cannot figure out the magic terms to put into the Googles to make this information pop out.

Comment: Is your piece of content(like to display in other pages) added in any site page of sharepoint online site?

Comment: @DikeshGandhi Yes it is. It is in another page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is not achievable using OOTB features.
Since there is [no master page to customize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages) in modern experience, there is no way you can update all the existing pages without laying hands on them.

Take a look at the [SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/single-part-app-pages?tabs=pnpposh), might give you an idea to apply the content for the pages to be created. One thing for sure, you will need enough privilege in the SharePoint site for the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think an SPFx extension could accomplish this but you would be restricted to the placeholders Microsoft have designated. You would need to deploy your extension to the tenant app catalog and then to all the sites where you need this content to surface. More information on SPFx extensions can be found here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions